# Festival TTS showing SIOD:ran out off storage message

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, festival

i am designing a front end for Festival TTS using it's C++ API

Everything is working fine in my programme but i have a problem that i am giving a drop down

option to user to select other languages when user select a language from drop down then

festival tts shows a message on console saying:

SIOD:ran out of storage

This message only shows if the text given to festival TTS is greater then 5 or 6 lines.

i think this message comes because SIOD's heap is not free when i am going to call a new language.

So please tell me the solution of this problem.

Thanks

Comment: i am using QT 4 for front end designing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](http://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/festlang-talk/2007-December/000716.html) (from the festival mailing list, 2007) suggests you may simply have to increase the heap to a size which can contain all the languages one might select.

I don't know how they ended up resolving this problem (the conversation thread appears to end after this email), whether it frees the memory or whether it keeps all used voices around... my guess is the latter.

Alternatively, if you can kill festival (i don't know your program structure) and reinitialise it from scratch when a new voice is selected, that may avoid having to set a very large heap...?

Comment: thanks drfrogsplat after increasing heap size my problem is solved